# Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle issue

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I configured my Symfony2 project to authentificate with FOSUserBundle and it works in general, but when I close my site tab in browser (being logged) and then open my site again in new tab i get:

> The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

and in my logs i see:

```
[2016-06-26 12:14:24] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} [] 
[2016-06-26 12:14:24] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"username":"dimitrioglo","provider":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Security\\UserProvider"} []
[2016-06-26 12:14:24] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template "AppBundle:Default:UserBundle:Registration:confirmed.html.twig.html.twig" (looked into: /app/Resources/views, /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form)." at /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 128 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to find template \"AppBundle:Default:UserBundle:Registration:confirmed.html.twig.html.twig\" (looked into: /app/Resources/views, /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form). at /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php:128, Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): Unable to find template \"AppBundle:Default:UserBundle:Registration:confirmed.html.twig.html.twig\" (looked into: /app/Resources/views, /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form). at /vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:215)"} [] 
[2016-06-26 12:14:24] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
```

And the thing that I don  not understand is why FOSUserBundle looks for `Registration:confirmed.html.twig.html.twig` instead of `Registration:confirmed.html.twig`

**Update 1:**

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant routing config?

Comment: see Update 1 please, it's default config, nothing special

Comment: Thanks, what route does the symfony debug toolbar show? The one you can see at the very bottom left, when you've got the toolbar open.

Comment: This site already in production, and It's complicated to up it on my local machine

Comment: Well to sum up my thoughts: I've never had this problem after installing FOSUser during probably 50 installations. So I assume you have some conflicting routing information somewhere, that causes the wrong route and thus template to be loaded. That's hard for me to debug without the source.

Comment: Thanks. For now I just logout and then sucessfully login, but it's not a solution.

Comment: @Dragony now I set the project locally and can provide more detailes, what info will be useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115653/discussion-between-d-dimitrioglo-and-dragony).